# Searchform not showing up

Tags: wordpress, genesis, search-form

I have made a custom searchform.php to go with a Genesis child theme! However my custom form is being replaced by the Genesis Default Searchform.

In the child theme's functions.php page I have added this snippet....

```
function search_form_no_filters(){
    // look for local searchform template
    $search_form_template = locate_template( 'searchform.php' );
    if ( '' !== $search_form_template ){
        // searchform.php exists, remove all filters
        remove_all_filters('get_search_form');
    }
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );
```

This naturally should pull up my custom form and replace the Default Gensis one but for some reson it's not!

Have I missed something out here?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think `add_filter` part is the reason for the form not being displayed.

use `add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'search_form_no_filters' );`